# Rails WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket

i try to use Rails Websockets on my production server. Everythings fine on development, but when i start my rails server in production mode and open the page it gives me this javascript error message:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://IP/websocket' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

I had some different problem with "eventmachine" but this was because i forget to add this line to websockets initializer:

```
config.standalone = true
```

I thought it is a problem with the https but i tried it over http and nothing works either.
Maybe somebody knows whats wrong. I use passenger as web server.

Comment: If you're not dead-set about using websocket-rails, look into [Plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io). It can also be used within a Rails application when you allow it to use it's own server (doesn't use Thin or Puma)... I'm biased, as I'm the author, but I got it deployed in my personal production sites and it works well.

Comment: P.S. I offered because I know the websockets-rails gem wasn't updates since Jun 5, 2014... It's development seem to have been put on hold (maybe for upcoming Rails 5... I don't know).

Comment: @Myst I dont need it for a chat system and it looks like plezi is about chat. Also i want to stay at websockets

Comment: Plezi is for pure websockets. Chat is simply the best way to demonstrate it's strengths - such as inter-websockets communications (broadcasting, unicasting), ease of use and scalability... But if you want to stay with websockets-rails, it's okay. I wish I could help you solve the issue with the we sockets-rails implementation.